# python script converted to exe is not working on double click

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, pyinstaller

I have converted my python script in exe file by using pyinstaller and it works fine while executing from power shell window. Now I have converted the same script in one file i.e only one exe file and trying to execute it on double click which not working and also not throwing any error. Is there any way to execute it on double click or open power shell window on double click?

Comment: Make sure the Python app does something visible. Maybe add an `input()` statement to a test version to see that it prompts for input?

Comment: please create a [example] if you want further assistance